# Palindrome Algorithm and JUnit 5 Tests

Tags: java, object-oriented, palindrome, junit

I have a "Palindrome" class that has some functions for verifying if certain things are Palindromes. For the verification, I have 2 different algorithms, one being recursive and the other iterative.

I'm happy with the algorithms however I'm unsure whether the way that I do the overloading and eventually parsing everything to the check charArray function is a smart thing.

I also have some Junit 5 Tests that prove that everything works. Here I'm just unsure if its good code with the multiple nests and the methods/tests I chose and if pretty much having duplicate code for the Iterative and Recursive algorithm is good.
Thank you in advance.

Palindrome Class

```
package com.gr;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author Lucifer Uchiha
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class Palindrome {

    /* Iterative */

    /**
     * Returns a boolean of whether the char array is a palindrome or not.
     * This is determined by using the iterative algorithm.
     *
     * @param chars char array containing the characters to be checked.
     * @return boolean of whether the char array is a palindrome or not.
     */
    public static boolean isCharArrayPalindromeIterative(char[] chars) {
        if (chars.length < 1)
            return false;
        char[] formattedChars = convertAllCharsToUpperCase(chars);
        boolean isPalindrome = true;
        for (int i = 0; i != formattedChars.length / 2; i++)
            if (formattedChars[i] != formattedChars[(formattedChars.length - 1) - i]) {
                isPalindrome = false;
                break;
            }
        return isPalindrome;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a boolean of whether the word of type String is a palindrome or not.
     * This is determined by using the iterative algorithm.
     *
     * @param word the word to be checked.
     * @return boolean of whether the word is a palindrome or not.
     */
    public static boolean isWordPalindromeIterative(String word) {
        return isCharArrayPalindromeIterative(word.toCharArray());
    }

    /**
     * Returns a boolean of whether the sentence of type String is a palindrome or not.
     * This is determined by using the iterative algorithm.
     *
     * @param sentence the sentence to be checked.
     * @return boolean of whether the sentence is a palindrome or not.
     */
    public static boolean isSentencePalindromeIterative(String sentence) {
        String newSentence = sentence.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
        return isWordPalindromeIterative(newSentence);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a boolean of whether the number of type byte (-128 to 127) is a palindrome or not.
     * This is determined by using the iterative algorithm.
     *
     * @param number the number to be checked.
     * @return boolean of whether the number is a palindrome or not.
     */
    public static boolean isNumberPalindromeIterative(byte number) {
        return isWordPalindromeIterative(String.valueOf(number));
    }

    /**
     * Returns a boolean of whether the number of type short (32,768 to 32,767) is a palindrome or not.
     * This is determined by using the iterative algorithm.
     *
     * @param number the number to be checked.
     * @return boolean of whether the number is a palindrome or not.
     */
    public static boolean isNumberPalindromeIterative(short number) {
        return isWordPalindromeIterative(String.valueOf(number));
    }

    /**
     * Returns a boolean of whether the number of type int (-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647) is a palindrome or not.
     * This is determined by using the iterative algorithm.
     *
     * @param number the number to be checked.
     * @return boolean of whether the number is a palindrome or not.
     */
    public static boolean isNumberPalindromeIterative(int number) {
        return isWordPalindromeIterative(String.valueOf(number));
    }

    /**
     * Returns a boolean of whether the number of type long (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807) is a palindrome or not.
     * This is determined by using the iterative algorithm.
     *
     * @param number the number to be checked.
     * @return boolean of whether the number is a palindrome or not.
     */
    public static boolean isNumberPalindromeIterative(long number) {
        return isWordPalindromeIterative(String.valueOf(number));
    }

    /**
     * Returns a List containing all the numbers that are palindromes in the range that is given from
     * start of type long to end of type long.
     * This is determined by using the iterative algorithm.
     *
     * @param start the start of the range, inclusive.
     * @param end   the end of the range, exclusive.
     * @return List containing all the numbers that are palindromes in the given range.
     */
    public static List<Long> getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeIterative(long start, long end) {
        List<Long> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for (long number = start; number != end; number++)
            if (isNumberPalindromeIterative(number))
                results.add(number);
        return results;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a List containing all the numbers that are palindromes in the range that is given from
     * start of type int to end of type int.
     * This is determined by using the iterative algorithm.
     *
     * @param start the start of the range, inclusive.
     * @param end   the end of the range, exclusive.
     * @return List containing all the numbers that are palindromes in the given range.
     */
    public static List<Integer> getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeIterative(int start, int end) {
        return convertLongListToIntegerList(getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeIterative((long) start, (long) end));
    }

    /**
     * Returns a List containing all the numbers that are palindromes in the range that is given from
     * start of type short to end of type short.
     * This is determined by using the iterative algorithm.
     *
     * @param start the start of the range, inclusive.
     * @param end   the end of the range, exclusive.
     * @return List containing all the numbers that are palindromes in the given range.
     */
    public static List<Short> getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeIterative(short start, short end) {
        return convertLongListToShortList(getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeIterative((long) start, (long) end));
    }

    /**
     * Returns a List containing all the numbers that are palindromes in the range that is given from
     * start of type byte to end of type byte.
     * This is determined by using the iterative algorithm.
     *
     * @param start the start of the range, inclusive.
     * @param end   the end of the range, exclusive.
     * @return List containing all the numbers that are palindromes in the given range.
     */
    public static List<Byte> getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeIterative(byte start, byte end) {
        return convertLongListToByteList(getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeIterative((long) start, (long) end));
    }

    /* Recursive */

    /**
     * Returns a boolean of whether the char array is a palindrome or not.
     * This is determined by using the recursive algorithm.
     *
     * @param chars char array containing the characters to be checked.
     * @return boolean of whether the char array is a palindrome or not.
     */
    public static boolean isCharArrayPalindromeRecursive(char[] chars) {
        if (chars.length < 1)
            return false;
        char[] formattedChars = convertAllCharsToUpperCase(chars);
        return recursion(formattedChars, 0, formattedChars.length - 1);
    }

    /**
     * The recursive algorithm.
     *
     * @param chars char array containing the characters to be checked.
     * @param start the left char being compared.
     * @param end   the right char being compared.
     * @return boolean of whether the char array is a palindrome or not.
     */
    private static boolean recursion(char[] chars, int start, int end) {
        if (start == end)
            return true;
        if (chars[start] != chars[end])
            return false;
        if (start < end + 1)
            return recursion(chars, ++start, --end);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a boolean of whether the word of type String is a palindrome or not.
     * This is determined by using the recursive algorithm.
     *
     * @param word the word to be checked.
     * @return boolean of whether the word is a palindrome or not.
     */
    public static boolean isWordPalindromeRecursive(String word) {
        return isCharArrayPalindromeRecursive(word.toCharArray());
    }

    /**
     * Returns a boolean of whether the sentence of type String is a palindrome or not.
     * This is determined by using the recursive algorithm.
     *
     * @param sentence the sentence to be checked.
     * @return boolean of whether the sentence is a palindrome or not.
     */
    public static boolean isSentencePalindromeRecursive(String sentence) {
        String newSentence = sentence.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
        return isWordPalindromeRecursive(newSentence);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a boolean of whether the number of type byte (-128 to 127) is a palindrome or not.
     * This is determined by using the recursive algorithm.
     *
     * @param number the number to be checked.
     * @return boolean of whether the number is a palindrome or not.
     */
    public static boolean isNumberPalindromeRecursive(byte number) {
        return isWordPalindromeRecursive(String.valueOf(number));
    }

    /**
     * Returns a boolean of whether the number of type short (32,768 to 32,767) is a palindrome or not.
     * This is determined by using the recursive algorithm.
     *
     * @param number the number to be checked.
     * @return boolean of whether the number is a palindrome or not.
     */
    public static boolean isNumberPalindromeRecursive(short number) {
        return isWordPalindromeRecursive(String.valueOf(number));
    }

    /**
     * Returns a boolean of whether the number of type int (-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647) is a palindrome or not.
     * This is determined by using the recursive algorithm.
     *
     * @param number the number to be checked.
     * @return boolean of whether the number is a palindrome or not.
     */
    public static boolean isNumberPalindromeRecursive(int number) {
        return isWordPalindromeRecursive(String.valueOf(number));
    }

    /**
     * Returns a boolean of whether the number of type long (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807) is a palindrome or not.
     * This is determined by using the recursive algorithm.
     *
     * @param number the number to be checked.
     * @return boolean of whether the number is a palindrome or not.
     */
    public static boolean isNumberPalindromeRecursive(long number) {
        return isWordPalindromeRecursive(String.valueOf(number));
    }

    /**
     * Returns a List containing all the numbers that are palindromes in the range that is given from
     * start of type long to end of type long.
     * This is determined by using the recursive algorithm.
     *
     * @param start the start of the range, inclusive.
     * @param end   the end of the range, exclusive.
     * @return List containing all the numbers that are palindromes in the given range.
     */
    public static List<Long> getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeRecursive(long start, long end) {
        List<Long> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for (long number = start; number != end; number++)
            if (isNumberPalindromeRecursive(number))
                results.add(number);
        return results;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a List containing all the numbers that are palindromes in the range that is given from
     * start of type int to end of type int.
     * This is determined by using the recursive algorithm.
     *
     * @param start the start of the range, inclusive.
     * @param end   the end of the range, exclusive.
     * @return List containing all the numbers that are palindromes in the given range.
     */
    public static List<Integer> getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeRecursive(int start, int end) {
        return convertLongListToIntegerList(getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeRecursive((long) start, (long) end));
    }

    /**
     * Returns a List containing all the numbers that are palindromes in the range that is given from
     * start of type short to end of type short.
     * This is determined by using the recursive algorithm.
     *
     * @param start the start of the range, inclusive.
     * @param end   the end of the range, exclusive.
     * @return List containing all the numbers that are palindromes in the given range.
     */
    public static List<Short> getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeRecursive(short start, short end) {
        return convertLongListToShortList(getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeRecursive((long) start, (long) end));
    }

    /**
     * Returns a List containing all the numbers that are palindromes in the range that is given from
     * start of type byte to end of type byte.
     * This is determined by using the recursive algorithm.
     *
     * @param start the start of the range, inclusive.
     * @param end   the end of the range, exclusive.
     * @return List containing all the numbers that are palindromes in the given range.
     */
    public static List<Byte> getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeRecursive(byte start, byte end) {
        return convertLongListToByteList(getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeRecursive((long) start, (long) end));
    }

    /**
     * Converts all letters in the given char array to capital letters if they aren't already.
     *
     * @param chars the start of the range, inclusive.
     * @return char array with the capitalized letters.
     */
    private static char[] convertAllCharsToUpperCase(char[] chars) {
        char[] formattedChars = new char[chars.length];
        for (int i = 0; i != chars.length; i++)
            if (Character.isLetter(chars[i]) && Character.isLowerCase(chars[i]))
                formattedChars[i] = Character.toUpperCase(chars[i]);
            else
                formattedChars[i] = chars[i];
        return formattedChars;
    }

    /**
     * Converts a List containing Long values to a List of Bytes.
     *
     * @param listOfLongs the List containing the Long values
     * @return the List containing the Byte values
     */
    private static List<Byte> convertLongListToByteList(List<Long> listOfLongs) {
        List<Byte> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Long i : listOfLongs)
            result.add(i.byteValue());
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Converts a List containing Long values to a List of Shorts.
     *
     * @param listOfLongs the List containing the Long values
     * @return the List containing the Shorts values
     */
    private static List<Short> convertLongListToShortList(List<Long> listOfLongs) {
        List<Short> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Long i : listOfLongs)
            result.add(i.shortValue());
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Converts a List containing Long values to a List of Integers.
     *
     * @param listOfLongs the List containing the Long values
     * @return the List containing the Integers values
     */
    private static List<Integer> convertLongListToIntegerList(List<Long> listOfLongs) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Long i : listOfLongs)
            result.add(i.intValue());
        return result;
    }
}
```

Palindrome Test Class

````
package com.gr;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@DisplayName("Palindrome Class")
public class PalindromeTest {

    // Nested Iterative
    @Nested
    class Iterative {

        @Nested
        class Word {

            @Test
            void testEmptyString() {
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeIterative(""));
            }

            @Test
            void testSingleLetter() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeIterative("A"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeIterative("a"));
            }

            @Test
            void testName() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeIterative("ABBA"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeIterative("Ava"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeIterative("bob"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeIterative("FAIL"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeIterative("Fail"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeIterative("fail"));
            }

            @Test
            void testWord() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeIterative("madam"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeIterative("Racecar"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeIterative("RADAR"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeIterative("FAIL"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeIterative("Fail"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeIterative("fail"));
            }
        }

        @Nested
        class Sentence {
            @Test
            void testEmptyString() {
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeIterative(""));
            }

            @Test
            void testSingleLetter() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeIterative("A"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeIterative("a"));
            }

            @Test
            void testSingleWord() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeIterative("madam"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeIterative("Racecar"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeIterative("RADAR"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeIterative("FAIL"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeIterative("Fail"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeIterative("fail"));
            }

            @Test
            void testSentence() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeIterative("Murder for a jar of red rum"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeIterative("Rats live on no evil star"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeIterative("step on no pets"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeIterative("This should fail"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeIterative("this should fail"));
            }

            @Test
            void testSentenceWithPunctuation() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeIterative("Do geese see God?"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeIterative("Live on time, emit no evil"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeIterative("live on time, emit no evil"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeIterative("Will this fail?"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeIterative("will this fail?"));
            }
        }

        @Nested
        class Number {

            @Test
            void testSingleLongNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative(0L));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative(1L));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative(3L));
            }

            @Test
            void testBiggerLongNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative(123454321L));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative(1234567890987654321L));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative(123456789L));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative(1234567890123456789L));
            }

            @Test
            void testNegativeLongNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative(-0L));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative(-123454321L));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative(-1234567890987654321L));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative(-123456789L));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative(-1234567890123456789L));
            }

            @Test
            void testSingleIntegerNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative(0));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative(1));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative(3));
            }

            @Test
            void testBiggerIntegerNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative(123454321));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative(123456789));
            }

            @Test
            void testNegativeIntegerNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative(-0));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative(-123454321));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative(-123456789));
            }

            @Test
            void testSingleShortNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative((short) 0));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative((short) 1));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative((short) 3));
            }

            @Test
            void testBiggerShortNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative((short) 12321));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative((short) 12345));
            }

            @Test
            void testNegativeShortNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative((short) -0));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative((short) -12321));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative((short) -12345));
            }

            @Test
            void testSingleByteNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative((byte) 0));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative((byte) 1));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative((byte) 3));
            }

            @Test
            void testBiggerByteNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative((byte) 121));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative((byte) 123));
            }

            @Test
            void testNegativeByteNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative((byte) -0));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative((byte) -121));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeIterative((byte) -123));
            }

        }

        @Nested
        class NumberInRange {
            @Test
            void testEmptyRangeLong() {
                List<Long> expected = new ArrayList<>();
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeIterative(122L, 130L));
            }

            @Test
            void testRangeSingleLong() {
                List<Long> expected = new ArrayList<>() {
                    {
                        add(1L);
                        add(2L);
                        add(3L);
                    }
                };
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeIterative(1L, 4L));
            }

            @Test
            void testRangeLong() {
                List<Long> expected = new ArrayList<>() {
                    {
                        add(121L);
                        add(131L);
                        add(141L);
                        add(151L);
                    }
                };
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeIterative(120L, 155L));
            }

            @Test
            void testNegativeRangeLong() {
                List<Long> expected = new ArrayList<>();
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeIterative(-131L, 0L));
            }

            @Test
            void testEmptyRangeInteger() {
                List<Integer> expected = new ArrayList<>();
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeIterative(122, 130));
            }

            @Test
            void testRangeSingleInteger() {
                List<Integer> expected = new ArrayList<>() {
                    {
                        add(1);
                        add(2);
                        add(3);
                    }
                };
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeIterative(1, 4));
            }

            @Test
            void testRangeInteger() {
                List<Integer> expected = new ArrayList<>() {
                    {
                        add(121);
                        add(131);
                        add(141);
                        add(151);
                    }
                };
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeIterative(120, 155));
            }

            @Test
            void testNegativeRangeInteger() {
                List<Integer> expected = new ArrayList<>();
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeIterative(-131, 0));
            }

            @Test
            void testEmptyRangeShort() {
                List<Short> expected = new ArrayList<>();
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeIterative((short) 122, (short) 130));
            }

            @Test
            void testRangeSingleShort() {
                List<Short> expected = new ArrayList<>() {
                    {
                        add((short) 1);
                        add((short) 2);
                        add((short) 3);
                    }
                };
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeIterative((short) 1, (short) 4));
            }

            @Test
            void testRangeShort() {
                List<Short> expected = new ArrayList<>() {
                    {
                        add((short) 121);
                        add((short) 131);
                        add((short) 141);
                        add((short) 151);
                    }
                };
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeIterative((short) 120, (short) 155));
            }

            @Test
            void testNegativeRangeShort() {
                List<Short> expected = new ArrayList<>();
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeIterative((short) -131, (short) 0));
            }

            @Test
            void testEmptyRangeByte() {
                List<Byte> expected = new ArrayList<>();
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeIterative((byte) 122, (byte) 125));
            }

            @Test
            void testRangeSingleByte() {
                List<Byte> expected = new ArrayList<>() {
                    {
                        add((byte) 1);
                        add((byte) 2);
                        add((byte) 3);
                    }
                };
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeIterative((byte) 1, (byte) 4));
            }

            @Test
            void testRangeByte() {
                List<Byte> expected = new ArrayList<>() {
                    {
                        add((byte) 101);
                        add((byte) 111);
                        add((byte) 121);
                    }
                };
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeIterative((byte) 100, (byte) 125));
            }

            @Test
            void testNegativeRangeByte() {
                List<Byte> expected = new ArrayList<>();
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeIterative((byte) -125, (byte) 0));
            }
        }
    }

    @Nested
    class Recursive {
        @Nested
        class Word {

            @Test
            void testEmptyString() {
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeRecursive(""));
            }

            @Test
            void testSingleLetter() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeRecursive("A"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeRecursive("a"));
            }

            @Test
            void testName() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeRecursive("ABBA"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeRecursive("Ava"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeRecursive("bob"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeRecursive("FAIL"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeRecursive("Fail"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeRecursive("fail"));
            }

            @Test
            void testWord() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeRecursive("madam"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeRecursive("Racecar"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeRecursive("RADAR"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeRecursive("FAIL"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeRecursive("Fail"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isWordPalindromeRecursive("fail"));
            }
        }

        @Nested
        class Sentence {
            @Test
            void testEmptyString() {
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeRecursive(""));
            }

            @Test
            void testSingleLetter() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeRecursive("A"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeRecursive("a"));
            }

            @Test
            void testSingleWord() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeRecursive("madam"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeRecursive("Racecar"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeRecursive("RADAR"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeRecursive("FAIL"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeRecursive("Fail"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeRecursive("fail"));
            }

            @Test
            void testSentence() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeRecursive("Murder for a jar of red rum"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeRecursive("Rats live on no evil star"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeRecursive("step on no pets"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeRecursive("This should fail"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeRecursive("this should fail"));
            }

            @Test
            void testSentenceWithPunctuation() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeRecursive("Do geese see God?"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeRecursive("Live on time, emit no evil"));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeRecursive("live on time, emit no evil"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeRecursive("Will this fail?"));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isSentencePalindromeRecursive("will this fail?"));
            }
        }

        @Nested
        class Number {

            @Test
            void testSingleLongNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive(0L));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive(1L));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive(3L));
            }

            @Test
            void testBiggerLongNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive(123454321L));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive(1234567890987654321L));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive(123456789L));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive(1234567890123456789L));
            }

            @Test
            void testNegativeLongNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive(-0L));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive(-123454321L));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive(-1234567890987654321L));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive(-123456789L));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive(-1234567890123456789L));
            }

            @Test
            void testSingleIntegerNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive(0));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive(1));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive(3));
            }

            @Test
            void testBiggerIntegerNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive(123454321));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive(123456789));
            }

            @Test
            void testNegativeIntegerNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive(-0));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive(-123454321));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive(-123456789));
            }

            @Test
            void testSingleShortNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive((short) 0));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive((short) 1));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive((short) 3));
            }

            @Test
            void testBiggerShortNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive((short) 12321));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive((short) 12345));
            }

            @Test
            void testNegativeShortNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive((short) -0));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive((short) -12321));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive((short) -12345));
            }

            @Test
            void testSingleByteNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive((byte) 0));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive((byte) 1));
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive((byte) 3));
            }

            @Test
            void testBiggerByteNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive((byte) 121));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive((byte) 123));
            }

            @Test
            void testNegativeByteNumber() {
                assertTrue(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive((byte) -0));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive((byte) -121));
                assertFalse(Palindrome.isNumberPalindromeRecursive((byte) -123));
            }

        }

        @Nested
        class NumberInRange {
            @Test
            void testEmptyRangeLong() {
                List<Long> expected = new ArrayList<>();
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeRecursive(122L, 130L));
            }

            @Test
            void testRangeSingleLong() {
                List<Long> expected = new ArrayList<>() {
                    {
                        add(1L);
                        add(2L);
                        add(3L);
                    }
                };
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeRecursive(1L, 4L));
            }

            @Test
            void testRangeLong() {
                List<Long> expected = new ArrayList<>() {
                    {
                        add(121L);
                        add(131L);
                        add(141L);
                        add(151L);
                    }
                };
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeRecursive(120L, 155L));
            }

            @Test
            void testNegativeRangeLong() {
                List<Long> expected = new ArrayList<>();
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeRecursive(-131L, 0L));
            }

            @Test
            void testEmptyRangeInteger() {
                List<Integer> expected = new ArrayList<>();
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeRecursive(122, 130));
            }

            @Test
            void testRangeSingleInteger() {
                List<Integer> expected = new ArrayList<>() {
                    {
                        add(1);
                        add(2);
                        add(3);
                    }
                };
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeRecursive(1, 4));
            }

            @Test
            void testRangeInteger() {
                List<Integer> expected = new ArrayList<>() {
                    {
                        add(121);
                        add(131);
                        add(141);
                        add(151);
                    }
                };
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeRecursive(120, 155));
            }

            @Test
            void testNegativeRangeInteger() {
                List<Integer> expected = new ArrayList<>();
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeRecursive(-131, 0));
            }

            @Test
            void testEmptyRangeShort() {
                List<Short> expected = new ArrayList<>();
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeRecursive((short) 122, (short) 130));
            }

            @Test
            void testRangeSingleShort() {
                List<Short> expected = new ArrayList<>() {
                    {
                        add((short) 1);
                        add((short) 2);
                        add((short) 3);
                    }
                };
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeRecursive((short) 1, (short) 4));
            }

            @Test
            void testRangeShort() {
                List<Short> expected = new ArrayList<>() {
                    {
                        add((short) 121);
                        add((short) 131);
                        add((short) 141);
                        add((short) 151);
                    }
                };
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeRecursive((short) 120, (short) 155));
            }

            @Test
            void testNegativeRangeShort() {
                List<Short> expected = new ArrayList<>();
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeRecursive((short) -131, (short) 0));
            }

            @Test
            void testEmptyRangeByte() {
                List<Byte> expected = new ArrayList<>();
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeRecursive((byte) 122, (byte) 125));
            }

            @Test
            void testRangeSingleByte() {
                List<Byte> expected = new ArrayList<>() {
                    {
                        add((byte) 1);
                        add((byte) 2);
                        add((byte) 3);
                    }
                };
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeRecursive((byte) 1, (byte) 4));
            }

            @Test
            void testRangeByte() {
                List<Byte> expected = new ArrayList<>() {
                    {
                        add((byte) 101);
                        add((byte) 111);
                        add((byte) 121);
                    }
                };
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeRecursive((byte) 100, (byte) 125));
            }

            @Test
            void testNegativeRangeByte() {
                List<Byte> expected = new ArrayList<>();
                assertEquals(expected, Palindrome.getAllNumberPalindromesInRangeRecursive((byte) -125, (byte) 0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 2):

This looks great, enjoyable to read despite the repetition.

---

```java
package com.gr;
```

Packages should associate with the author, so they should be something like `com.github.lucifer.palindrome` for example. But depending on whether this code is being published or not, it does not matter in this case.

---

This would be a great exercise for object-oriented programming by creating an interface and having two separate implementations:

```java
public interface PalindromeTester;
public class IterativePalindromeTester implements PalindromeTester;
public class RecursivePalindromeTester implements PalindromeTester;
```

That would solve one-half of your overloading question. The other half is the `Number`/`CharArray`/`Word` thing, you should drop that from the name as it is obvious from the accepted parameters. IT would also cleanup your test-case a bit, as it would be two different test-classes. You even have an `abstract` test-class and extend that and only set a different instance of `PalindromeTester` on `BeforeEach`.

Another thing is, if you can live with widening given values, you could only provide a single method accepting a `long`. Any `short`/`int` will be automatically converted, but that, of course, requires a widening operation under the hood.

There's also `Number`/`BigInteger`, which you might want to include.

On another note, you could drop `char[]` in favor of `CharSequence`. The later is the base for many different classes (including `String`, so no overload required) and represents the intent a little better. Regarding that, if you accept any letter, including foreign languages, you most likely want to to work on code-points (`int`) instead of `char`s. In UTF-8/UTF-16, not all letters are only a single byte, but can be composed of multiples bytes (up to four, hence `int`).

---

```java
 * Returns a boolean of whether the number of type short (32,768 to 32,767)
```

Don't include min/max values like that in the documentation. First, it's redundant as it is obvious from the used type. Second, it is prone to typos, like in this case.

---

```java
        List<Long> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for (long number = start; number != end; number++)
            if (isNumberPalindromeRecursive(number))
                results.add(number);
```

Be aware that this is autoboxing, meaning a primitive is automatically converted to an `Object` instance.

---

```java
for (int i = 0; i != formattedChars.length / 2; i++)
```

First, I'm a persistent advocate of "real" names for loop variables, like `index` or `counter`.

Second, you should revise the break condition to be more robust by checking whether the value is equal or greater the half length.

---

```java
        boolean isPalindrome = true;
        for (int i = 0; i != formattedChars.length / 2; i++)
            if (formattedChars[i] != formattedChars[(formattedChars.length - 1) - i]) {
                isPalindrome = false;
                break;
            }
        return isPalindrome;
```

Don't store the result, return it directly.

````java
        for (int i = 0; i != formattedChars.length / 2; i++)
            if (formattedChars[i] != formattedChars[(formattedChars.length - 1) - i])
                return false;
        
        return true;
```
````

Comment: Hi, thx for the extensive feedback. gr are my initials which is why I named the package com.gr but I could change it to my Github name since I have a repo there for this project. Im guessing I can create an Interface and 2 implementations for the code itself and also the test cases?

Comment: I wouldn't create an interface for the test-cases, but an `abstract` test-case with concrete implementations for each implementation would be suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Having a common interface for the algorithm would solve the code duplication between tests for different implementations. You create a set of tests that any implementation of the interface should fulfill and then just throw different implementations at it (see the [L in SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)).

For testing a large set of simple string inputs, put the valid entries into one array and invalid ones in another and create two tests that loop over each array.